# Java - Find Regex to match in String

Tags: java, regex

I need some help because i'm junior in Java and after some research on the web
I can't find a solution.
So my problem:

```
String str : size="A4"
```

I would like to extract 'A4' with a regex by giving the word "size" in the regex.
How can I do ?

Comment: Where is the regex you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Pattern [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that matches your conditions.
2. Generate a Matcher [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) that handles the input String
3. let the Matcher find the desired value (by using `Matcher.group(group)` )

.

```
//1. create Pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("size=\\\"([A-Za-z0-9]{2})\\\"");

//2. generate Matcher
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);

//3. find value using groups(int)
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works ! :)

From this regex : ("size=\\\"([A-Za-z0-9]{2})\\\"")

A last question : how to allow all characters and without specify "{2}" ? 

Thank you very much everyone ! :)

Comment: I tried but i can't find how to allow all characteres.
Any idea ? :)

Comment: Hello,

Any char is "."
The {2} is here to indicate you must have 2 char between your comas. So :
`[A-Za-z0-9]{2}`
Is equivalent to :
`[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]`

I recommand you to read some tuto about regular expressions :
https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

You can use this site to help you for the beginning :
https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Matcher m=Pattern.compile("size\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher("size=\"A4\"");
        while(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

`A4`

http://ideone.com/FqMuTA

Regex breakdown:

`size\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"`

- `size` matches `size` literally
- `\\s*=\\s*` matches 0 or more white spaces leading or trailing the
  `=` sign
- `\"` matches a double quote
- `([^\"]*)` matches 0 or more characters(which is not a double quote
  `[^\"]`) and remembers the captured text as back-reference 1 i.e
  nothing but captured group number 1 used below in the while loop
- `\"` we match the ending double quote

You can find more info on regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)